# tkprof error. Not found even when db is installed

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Do we need to install `tkprof` separately? My `database` server is running in this instance. i have also another instance in which `tkprof` is working fine. if we install `database`, will `tkprof` not come automatically?

But in this environment it is giving error. If it needs to install, what are the steps to do for it?

[image]

Comment: Is TKPROF in path? I don't speak Unix, but - "command not found" sounds like that.

Comment: there is some issue. yes it is unix. $ORACLE_HOME/bin is not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, tkprof is included with the database software.

Check your ORACLE_HOME and PATH environment variables.

You should see 'tkprof' in your $ORACLE_HOME/bin directory, right alongside things like sqlplus, dbca, and impdp.